# Mux KLV STANAG data into MPEG-TS stream in Python

Tags: python, mpeg2-ts, klvdata, stanag

I have some MPEGTS video streams and i need to mux KLV metadata into these. KLV data may e in a .pcap format or any another binary format. Any ideas about how can i perform this using some Python library?